# Syntax to Redirect to Input/Output to in C (UNIX)

Tags: c, io, fork, mkfifo

I am trying to find the syntax that will let me redirect standard input output toward a named pipe after using the mkfifo() function and creating a child process using fork.

Which man page should I be looking at for the syntax?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various sections of man page can serve your various purposes.
Generally,
Section 1 contain syntax for executable programs or shell command .

```
man mkfifo
```

Section 3 contain syntax for Library call ( used in c programs).

```
man 3 mkfifo
```

Edit:
I think i misunderstood the question..if u need the syntax for a command for redirection, check

```
man dup
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you referred [this](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/)

gives you idea about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `dup2` function. Standard Input is file descriptor #0 and Standard Output is #1.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html